# mysql command in c script

Tags: mysql, c, mingw

I have tried to compile a program on MingW64, and there's an error when I try to run a makefile.

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -std=gnu99 -O3   -c -o mysql.o mysql.c
mysql.c:5:25: fatal error: mysql/mysql.h: No such file or directory 
include <mysql/mysql.h>
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mysql.o] Error 1
```

I use MingW64 and I understand that I need this mysql file something. So I download mysql, and I do find a mysql.h file, and a mysql program, but where do I put it, so that MingW64 can find it?

Comment: You put it in your include path(s) that are searched for include files between `<` and `>`. Or you add the path to `mysql.h` in those include paths.

Comment: put in same folder where your program file is there